# Count number of results, which search is better? Google custom search API or Bing API?

Tags: bing, bing-api

I want a count for the number of results obtained when i post a query. Which search API is better for this? I found google custom search API very unreliable about the count that it returns and it allows only 100 free queries per day, on the other hand Bing API allows 5000 queries per month and returns the same count as shown on the bing.com. But if you put the same queries to google.com and bing.com then the resulting cout they give differs a lot and google's is more reliable in that aspect. I am confused, can anybody help?

Comment: Is web scraping helpful for accurate google count? is it legal?

Comment: I found out that the count returned by google API is only an estimate and not the actual count. Does anybody know how to get an actual count?